# Backbone.js and non-model objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am currently using `Backbone.js` as a front-end MVC system. Assume, however, that I have objects which are not necessarily models (for example, an object which parses JSON from a successful AJAX request).

How should I best represent these objects? I don't think they're "models" in the traditional sense. Should they just be normal JavaScript objects? It seems like `Backbone` should have some way to account for this.

Open to any feedback.

Comment: Why do you think they are not models?

Comment: Could you put those into a namespace file as helpers?

Comment: I don't think they're models because they don't represent data - there is no state - this is an object that represents a strategy of parsing.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects doesn't have to be models just because you are using Backbone.

The Backbone Model object is basically just a wrapper around a regular object, that has methods for accessing the data, and events that you can use to subscribe to changes.

If you want to put the objects in a Backbone Collection, then they will be wrapped in models if they aren't already.

Comment: so effectively backbone has no way to account for needs other than that  can be accounted for through models? I resort to creating my own javascript classes?

Comment: @praks5432: You can extend the Model type to make your own model types with your own methods if you like, or you can just use regular Javascript objects.

Comment: thanks Guffa - is there a suitable place where I can have discussions about issues like this? (by that I mean design decisions)

Answer (score -1):

Thank you that you did not ask about controllers that do not exist in Backbone actually.

To my mind, there is no need to implement parsers  (or any other services) as models in Backbone, because in this case you pull with a parser a lot of orphan code that you are never going to use.

Comment: ...what? Ok this is going to move stuff away from the question, but I can think of reasons to  have backbone models.

Comment: You never validate or save your data? You don't monitor changes on it? I'm afraid you lose a lot of Backbone power by not using models

Comment: @nikoshr I think you misunderstood my reply. Read it again, meaning a question it answered, please. Sure I use models, but not for parsers. And I don't recommend to use it for parsers (or any other services), because in this case you pull with a parser a lot of orphan code that you never going to use.
No need to implement anything as a model, of course, that is.

Comment: You wrote **no need to implement anything as a model in Backbone**, your answer does seem to indicate that models are never useful. But you're right, I certainly misunderstood your intent.